# Application name is missing in Spring Boot logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

For example, people usually get something like this (my-service-id is the application name)

```
2016-02-11 17:12:45.404  INFO [my-service-id] 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MySimpleComponentMakingARequest     : ...
```

But I get something like

```
2016-02-11 17:12:45.404  INFO 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MySimpleComponentMakingARequest     : ...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to learn more about how to [configure pattern of spring boot logs](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+configure+logging+pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to configure that via `application.properties`

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=stackoverflow
logging.pattern.level= %5p [${spring.application.name}]
```

If want to use the project info defined in your pom.xml you could do something like:

```
spring.application.name=@project.name@ @project.version@
```

Full documentation can be found here: [logging features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging)

Comment: Adding the loggin.pattern.level statement worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome, remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative to have this information:
If you add [Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-log-integration) to your project, it will put correlation ids (traceId/spanId) and your application name to your log entries.