# To print myApp name in Springboot logging

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I have a springboot application which prints random logs. I also want to include myApp name in those logs. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application name is missing in Spring Boot logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951325/application-name-is-missing-in-spring-boot-logs)

Answer (score 1):

Add properties listed below to your `application.properties` and application name will be appended to all your logs:

```
spring.application.name=my-spring-boot-application
logging.pattern.level= %5p [${spring.application.name}]
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working

Comment: How do you print random logs?

Comment: I just have an array of strings consisting of log-levels and I am randomly picking something from array and printing logs .

Comment: Maybe you don't use logger properly. Please check the first section on the following link (https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/logging-application-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties you configured the name with:

```
spring.application.name=your-app-name
```

Then you can just Autowire it in with:

```
@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String applicationName;
```

And then finally just log it:

```
 LOGGER.info("Your application name: {}", applicationName);
```

Comment: It did work . But I want to implement the same in my log4j2-spring.xml file

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly yet, but for me `@Value` only works on a setter method and only if the class variable is static. Any other placement or not static and in any tests the variable will be null. Possibly a set up issue.